# How do I set my StackExchange profile to use Dark Mode Theme?

Tags: color, interface-design, user-experience

Dumb question, but how do I set my profile to use Dark Mode theme?
I managed to do it for StackOverflow, but can't recall how I did it and can't find where to set it for this profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to set it **per stack**. There's no "global" setting and only **some** stacks have dark mode, not all of them.

`Profile > Settings > Interface`

GD.SE has no dark mode, thus no Interface setting.

Comment: Yeah, I found the setting in SO and you are spot on - it is where I expected to find it, and SE has no such setting. Bummer...oh, well.